New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 5:01:43 PM - The deployment 'BlockBlobStorageDeployment' failed with error(s)
BlockBlob Storage Bicep Code:
@minLength(3)
@maxLength(24)
param storageAccName string = uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: storageAccName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'BlockBlobStorage'
}


PowerShell Code:
PS C:\Windows\System32> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name 'BlockBlobStorageDeployment'  -TemplateFile 'D:\LearnBicep\uniquestringdemo.bicep' -ResourceGroupName 'vivekchak-rg'  -Mode Incremental
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 5:01:43 PM - The deployment 'BlockBlobStorageDeployment' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: Values for request parameters are invalid: kind, sku. For more information, see - https://aka.ms/storageaccounttypes (Code:InvalidValuesForRequestParameters)
CorrelationId:
DeploymentName          : BlockBlobStorageDeployment
ResourceGroupName       : vivekchak-rg
ProvisioningState       : Failed
Timestamp               : 12/29/2024 11:31:39 AM
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            :
Parameters              :
                          Name              Type                       Value
                          ================  =========================  ==========
                          storageAccName    String                     "rr5rrwknkv5nc"

Outputs                 :
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :


While deploying the BlockBlobStorage also, I'm getting the above error here.
Where the issue is happening on?

The error seems to be because Premium_LRS is not a valid SKU for BlockBlobStorage. Could you try Using Premium_ZRS instead for BlockBlobStorage accounts in your Bicep code @VivekAnandChakravarthy


The deployment 'BlockBlobStorageDeployment' failed with error(s) while using Premium_LRS for BlockBlobStorage

Issue seems to with the use of Premium_LRS with the BlockBlobStorage kind which is not supportive.
Here for the mentioned kind the supportive sku is Premium_ZRS
for BlockBlobStorage.
Sample bicep:
@minLength(3)
@maxLength(24)
param storageAccName string = uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-05-01' = {
  name: storageAccName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  sku: {
    name: 'Premium_ZRS' 
  }
  kind: 'BlockBlobStorage'
}

Deployement:
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name 'BlockBlobStorageDeployment' -TemplateFile '/home/main.bicep' -ResourceGroupName 'vinay-rg' -Mode Incremental



Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json#types-of-storage-accounts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=bicep#storage-account-type-parameters
